Connecting the PHI2 pins on W65C22
A year ago, I started designing my own 8-bit CPU with discrete transistors (I know this is a crazy goal, but I'm mostly doing it to learn). Now before I order everything for my CPU, I created a PCB design for some memory and interface ics.
One of those interface ics is the W65C22 from Western Design Company. (This ic is connected to some joysticks so I can make simple games). My CPU has 16 address pins, ofcourse 8 bus lines and 2 pins: WE (Write Enable) and RE (Read Enable).
I have looked extensively into the datasheet of the W65C22 and also some places where they are used, such as the old Commodore VIC-20 computer. I found that the PHI2 pin on the chip is supposed to the clock, but because of my architecture of my CPU, I'm not sure if it's still directly compatible.
If anyone could give me a clear explaination on how the PHI2 pin is supposed to be used, it would be well appreciated!
Updated:
I looked at another datasheet of the W65C22 and here I found a timing diagram (Figure 4-2) on how to use the PHI2 pin together with the data, address, RWB and chip enable pins.
After implementing this timing scheme on a Arduino Mega for testing, it seems to work fine...

A very warm welcome to the site. Am a bit confused by your question: the 6502 PHI2 output connects to the 6522 PHI2 input...and that's about it :-) Reasons why it might not be that straightforward are in the details of your transistor 6502 and you don't say much about that in your question. So you'd have to significantly expand your question (don't add new info in comments, edit the question) and explain that before anyone could answer further.

I'm a bit confused. On one hand you're building your own CPU from not just TTL but transistors, on the other hand you've issues reading the simple diagram on p46 of the 2010 W65C22 data sheet? Also, if you're already building a whole CPU from transistors, why not add a few (or a single TTL) to read the joysticks? Somehow the premises don't add up. Maybe it helps if you'd describe your project a bit more in detail. (P.S.: from what's said, your WE/RE may as well work as PHI2 regarding register access - but that's speculation).

Hi Raff. I understand your confussion, but I had a older version of de datasheet in front of me where I couldn't find the correct timing diagram I needed... And you are right, I should be able to connect the RE/WE pin from the CPU directly to the PHI2 pin now that I have the correct timing diagram. Thanks for your comment!

In the early days of microprocessors, there were two approaches to handling memory accesses:

Having a processor indicate the address associated with a memory address and the "direction" of that access (read vs write), and then having a signal to indicate when all of the aforementioned signals should be considered valid.

Having a processor indicate a memory address, and then having a signal which indicates that it should be read and a different signal that indicates that it should be written.


Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.  The 6502 used the former approach, and many devices designed for use with it do as well.  My preferred approach to interfacing with such devices is to use a NAND to produce an active-high signal from the active-low read-enable and write-enable signals, and use an address pin to select the direction.  This will require using separate addresses for reading and writing, but will ensure that any setup/hold times related to the direction input are satisfied.
